# Migrate pre-existing (not encrypted) realm DB to a new encrypted one

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to figure out how do I apply encryption to an existing un-encrypted realm db?

Setting up realm with encryption from scratch was easy - just provide the key at:

```
        .encryptionKey(getRealmKey())
```

But my app is already out there in the wild and I would like to keep it working with all existing data.

Here is a naive implementation of it so far (crashing with "      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The destination file must not exist":

```
 @Provides
    public Realm realm(RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
        File encryptedFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "encrypted_realm");
        realm.writeEncryptedCopyTo(encryptedFile, getRealmKey());

    return realm;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration() {

    Realm.init(context);
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("db")
            .schemaVersion(7)
            .migration(new AppRealmMigration())
            .build();

    return config;
}

private byte[] getRealmKey() {
    return new byte[64];
}
```

Comment: There is `encryptedFile` already. If there is `encryptedFile` already, you don't need to invoke `realm.writeEncryptedCopyTo`.

Comment: I am getting this exception on first run after a fresh install of the app

Comment: Are `Realm realm(RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration)` injected twice?Please add additional logs.

Comment: not twice - the first upper method is getting the realm configuration from the method below it

Comment: IllegalArgumentException said you already had `encrypted_realm` file. Is there another `new File(context.getFilesDir(), "encrypted_realm")` or is your Realm provider called every launch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. It will detect the old Realm and copy it as an encrypted copy if needed:

```
public Realm getInstance() {
    RealmConfiguration newConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("encrypted.realm") // Different name than old
            .encryptionKey(getKey())
            .build();

    // If new file exist, assume it has already been migrated
    File newRealmFile = new File(newConfig.getPath());
    if (newRealmFile.exists()) {
        return Realm.getInstance(newConfig);
    } else {
        // Migrate old Realm and delete old
        RealmConfiguration old = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(old);
        realm.writeEncryptedCopyTo(newRealmFile, getKey());
        realm.close();
        Realm.deleteRealm(old);
        return Realm.getInstance(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct and the flow is as such - check whether encryption file exists - if it does, just use a realm configuration that provides the key to decrypt it. If the encryption file doesn't exist you need to migrate to it - create a new, encrypted file and pass it to realm.writeEncryptedCopyTo(encryptedFile, key);

Comment: @Christian Melchior: Thanks, is there any way to not change realm file name. Or method to check realm db is encrypt or not.

Comment: No, you need to rename it while doing the copy, but nothing prevents you from re-naming the new encrypted file again after the copy is over. You can use `configuration.getPath()` to get the full path to the file.